# How to execute a HTTP request in a seperate thread and return response

Tags: java, http, threadpool, executor

I have a service method that does a considerable amount of looping and executing HTTP request for each loop.
So my intention is to use a seperate thread for this service. How can i correctly achieve this using `ExecutorService`.

```
private ExecutorService executorService;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
}

@Override
public ResponseDto getSummary() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Callable<ResponseDto> task = () -> {
        try {
            executeRequests();
            log.debug("Fetching summary details ompleted");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception occurred", e);
        }
    };

    Future<ResponseDto> future = executorService.submit(task);
    return future.get();
}


private ResponseDto executeRequests() { 

  // executing HTTP requests inside loops and returning ResponseDto

}
```

So upto now i have implemented like above. Im not sure about how to return the response when the work is done. Any suggestions?

Comment: Method [submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-), in interface `ExecutorService` returns a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). Maybe consider implementing [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) rather than `Runnable`.

Comment: That sounds good. care to give an answer please?

Comment: Care to do some research on [executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)?

Comment: @Abra updated with `Callable`

Comment: Use a callback to process the result asynchronously. If your application has a message processing loop (eg some GUI like Swing, JavaFX ...) put the callback in the message queue. You might also look at `CompletableFuture`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `executor.invokeAll`.

**An example:**

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); // create threads when it needs
        final List<Callable<Optional<YourResponse>>> callableList = new ArrayList<>();

            callableList.add(() -> Optional.ofNullable(service.
                .getYourData()));       

        final List<Future<Optional<YourResponse>>> listFutures =
            executor.invokeAll(callableList);

        listFutures.forEach(future -> {
            try {
                future.get().ifPresent(response -> //doAnyThing... Ex: your Response handled, reduced...);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });

        executor.shutdown();

        return yourResponses came from future.get().ifPresent(;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // your handler
    }
```